# Facebook App Insights for Website "app" shows all zero's?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, xfbml

If you create a FB App for the lone purpose of getting an App ID for XFBML Like Button Plugin implementation should you see data for the app insights?

We have had the XFBML Like Button on our blog for a while now and each post gets anywhere between 5 and 3,000 likes (I realized that not all of these occur on the site itself) but when I go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/MYAPPID/insights it shows me all zeros for the number of users, shares and performance.  Is this normal because my app is really only a way to register the site with FB or could this be an implementation issue?  It would make sense to me that I should be getting some stats under the sharing section for "Stream Published Stories Created" or "Links Posted" because that is what the Like button is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include proper facebook metadata on your domain?

You must specify an App ID or an Admin ID as so:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="user_id" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your_app_id" />
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

Also note:

> **Why does the count next to my Like Button not match what I see in Insights?** The count next to the Like Button represents the sum of Like Button clicks, News Feed likes, News Feed comments, and shares on Facebook.

Comment: Yes the correct meta tags are in there.  Also, I am aware that the Like Button count includes "likes" that occur off the site.